# Xpath: why normalize-space could not remove the empty space and \n?

Tags: xpath, scrapy

For the following code:

```
<a class="title" href="the link">
Low price
<strong>computer</strong>
you should not miss
</a>
```

I used this xpath code to scrapy:

```
response.xpath('.//a[@class="title"]//text()[normalize-space()]').extract()
```

I got the following result:

```
u'\n                  \n                  Low price ', u'computer', u' you should not miss'
```

Why two `\n` and many empty spaces before `low price` was not removed by `normalize-space()` for this example?

Another question: how to combine the 3 parts as one scraped item as `u'Low price computer you should not miss'`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please try this:

```
'normalize-space(.//a[@class="title"])'
```

Comment: Your answer works and solves both problems (removing empty spaces, as well as joining three parts together). However, it shows **the first item only** on this website (http://www.simplyhired.com/search?t=pathologist&qw=speech&fed=9&ws=50&fdb=30).

Comment: My above comment is due to an incorrect restricting xpath code.  Now everything works!

Comment: Can you tell us how exactly you got away with this, I have the exact same problem : only the first item is normalized.

Answer (score 2):

I already had the same problem, try this:

```
[item.strip() for item in response.xpath('.//a[@class="title"]//text()').extract()]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your call to normalize-space() is in a predicate. That means you are selecting text nodes where (the effective boolean value of) `normalize-space()` is true. You aren't selecting the result of normalize-space: for that you would want

```
.//a[@class="title"]//text()/normalize-space()
```

(which needs XPath 2.0)

The second part of your question: just use

```
string(.//a[@class="title"])
```

(assuming scrapy-spider allows you to use an XPath expression that returns a string, rather than one that returns nodes).

Comment: Your xpath code gives me error message: `  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Scrapy-1.0.3-py2.7.egg/scrapy/http/response/text.py", line 109, in xpath
    return self.selector.xpath(query)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Scrapy-1.0.3-py2.7.egg/scrapy/selector/unified.py", line 100, in xpath
    raise ValueError(msg if six.PY3 else msg.encode("unicode_escape"))
ValueError: Invalid XPath`

Comment: Which XPath? - I gave two. I did warn you that both might not work in this environment. What a pathetic error message, though.

Comment: The first xpath code.  You mentioned xpath 2.0 is needed. But I don't know how to check xpath version in Mac OSX. Thanks!

Comment: The easiest way to check if your XPath processor supports 2.0 is to try a 2.0 expression, e.g. `/*/name()`